# What is the strength of Mist wallet encryption?

Tags: ether, wallets, mist, password

I would like to know what is the strength of the encryption the Mist wallet provides with the password-protected files, and if I can just throw these files around (even uploading them to the internet) if my password is strong enough.

What I mean to ask is: If my password is 304 bit key, is the encryption on the key files is 304 as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Mist is using go-ethereum (geth) as a backend.

Per the string in the JSON keystore file:

```
"cipher":"aes-128-ctr"
```

> AES-128 = [Advanced Encryption Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)
>
> CTR = [Counter Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29)

"CTR is used if you want good parallelization (ie. speed), instead of CBC/OFB/CFB."

I *think* this cipher variable can be modified if you wanted to try something different. (More digging through go-ethereum would be needed.)

*edit*: Nope. [It must be aes-128-ctr for now.](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/crypto/key_store_passphrase.go#L188)

Comment: Which means I can safely throw these files around, provided I'm the only one who knows the password, right?

Comment: @xfotlm I would avoid it, but you could if you want to I guess. (Based on your risk tolerance.)